# Init scripts per user

Tags: ubuntu, boot, init

There is a script (more like a command) which I would like to be executed on a per user-login basis. I've heard of `init.d` scripts but those require root permissions and are not per-user customizable (AFAIK). Simply put, I am looking for something along the lines of `.bashrc` which would be executed only once per user login.

To detail a bit about the scenario, I currently use a Ubuntu guest OS on a Windows host (emulation courtesy of VirtualBox). Every time I login to my guest OS, I need a `mount` command to be executed which would mount my shared folders to a common directory in the user's home directory.

Comment: Doesn't `mount` require root, or at least a root config change to make volumes mountable by non-root users?

Comment: @Rich: Indeed it does; I don't mind seeing a password prompt when I fire up my shell. It's just that the `mount` command is pretty complicated and I didn't want to put in extra effort of executing a helper script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the different options here: http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en , you probably want the PostLogin option

Comment: The problem here is that all of those options require a change in the /etc/* files which require root privileges. Isn't there any file I can create/edit to ensure that a script is executed only when *I* login to the system? Something like `.bashrc` which is invoked on every bash session and is private to the user?

Comment: ok, I missed the root rights, obviously. You can try writing a .xinitrc or a .xsession file: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xinitrc.html

Comment: no, that won work either. What will work is to add your script to the startup applications (provided ubuntu has such a thing). In fedora you get there from system -> preferences -> starup applications. Here there is a ubuntu link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup

Comment: I think it's strange that there isn't a standard for this in Linux. Everyone needs a different method according to the distribution? Or perhaps there is a standard?

Answer (score 5):

The standard place for commands to run when you log in is **`~/.profile`**. There are some environments where this file is skipped when you log in directly in graphics mode, but with Ubuntu 10.04, `~/.profile` is read by gdm, kdm, lxdm and xdm login scripts (in addition to when you log in on a text console or over ssh).

If you have a `~/.bash_profile`, your `~/.profile` will sometimes be skipped. It is best to put only the following two lines in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.profile
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then put login-time actions in `~/.profile` and shell customizations in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You've resolved a 2-day journey as to why .bashrc and .profile were being ignored at login. The other admin made a .bash_profile at one time -- after erasing it and relogging, everything worked wonderfully again! Woot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't grasp all the subtleties, but I think that you can do that if you are using ubuntu, I guess that you could just write a script for each user (or a script with different rules depending on 'whoami') and, if they are using gnome (as it's default for Ubuntu), add that script to startup applications.

Answer (score 1):

Linux cron (written by Paul Vixie, so called Vixie cron) has the meta keyword `@reboot`, which will start things as the crontab owner upon reboot.  See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/