# ~/.profile is not sourced on startup

Tags: linux, login, .profile

I've recently installed virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper on Linux Mint 10 LXDE. For convenience I've added the standard WORKON_HOME settings to my ~/.profile

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then I've noticed that `workon` does not work after login, which means the above commands were not run. If I `source ~/.profile` then it works. I'm really not sure what could cause `.profile` not being run? I've checked and I don't have `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~/.profile` is only sourced for interactive login shells. If you're starting a shell that's interactive but it's not a login shell, then `~/.bashrc` is sourced.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980) and [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/205394/init-scripts-per-user/205972#205972) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, looks like LXTerminal does not work with `~/.profile`.

Comment: @Beres Botond: You originally wrote that your setting didn't work when you *logged in*. Now you're saying that it doesn't work when you *run LXTerminal*. If you're launching an LXTerminal from your window manager, you're not logging in. Generally speaking, ~/.profile *is* the place to set environment variables so that they affect the environment of all programs run after login, but you have to log out entirely and back in for those settings to have that effect.